# Is it possible to add 3rd party libraries to CoronaSDK application for iOS?

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I'm developing a game in CoronaSDK. Recently I've been asked if it's possible to add a `Yogi Play` library to it. As I see it comes as a iOS framework, with resources like NIB files... And they give instructions to integrate it via custom ViewControllers from CocoaTouch.

So, is it possible to put it into a Corona SDK application and call somehow? Or is there any other way to bundle Yogi Play with Corona?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you get the Enterprise license.